# Jquery select parent class div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to write some simple jQuery to display class `bl3` when class `blc3` is clicked.
I've got it working to show every class `bl3` when a `blc3` class is clicked, but I want it to open only the specific `bl3` that relates to the clicked `blc3`.

HTML :

```html
<div class="product pro">
    <img class="product-img pro" src="'.$product[" imagesrc "].'"/>
    <div class="product-actions pro">
        <div class="info-block pro bl3" style="display:none;">
            <div class="product-title pro">Ships to:</div>
            <div class="product-description pro">Days:</div>
            <div class="product-sale pro">UK</div>
            <div class="product-prize pro">7</div>
            <div class="button-buy pro">Buy now</div>
            <div class="add pro">Add</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav titlen pro">TESTING</div>
    <div class="nav pro boxp">
        <ul>
            <li class="active blc1"><span class="icon-tag f15"></span> '.$product["price"].'
                <br>
            </li>
            <li class="blc2"><span class="icon-time f15"></span> '.$product["stime"].'
                <br>
            </li>
            <li class="blc3"><span class="icon-plane f15"></span> '.$product["sto"].'
                <br>
            </li>
            <li><span class="icon-zoom-in f15"></span> '.$product["sto"].'
                <br>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY :

```js
$j(".blc3").click(function() {
    $j(this).parent().prev('.bl3').css('display','block');  
});
```

Unfortunately, this does not select the correct element.

The jQuery below works for displaying all elements with class `bl3`:

```
$j('.bl3').css('display','block');
```

But I want to display only the one that relates to the clicked `blc3`.
How to just display the one appropriate `bl3`?

Comment: so if `li class=blc3` is clicked, you want it do what?

Comment: I want it to display class bl3. Not everyclass bl3 but the previous found. (2 divs above)

Comment: So, you have one `<div class="product pro">` for each product? And you want to show the `bl3` for the particular product that was clicked?

Comment: Indeed. I tried this but also displaying every class bl3. $j(this).parents().find('.bl3').css('display','block');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest the jQuery selector below. For each `.blc3` that is clicked, it looks for the parent `div.product` and then searches for a `.bl3` in that element.

```js
$('.blc3').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('div.product').find('.bl3').show();
});
```

Documentation: [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Test below:

```js
$('.blc3').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('div.product').find('.bl3').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product pro">
  <img class="product-img pro" src="'.$product[" imagesrc "].'"/>
  <div class="product-actions pro">
    <div class="info-block pro bl3" style="display:none;">
      <div class="product-title pro">Ships to:</div>
      <div class="product-description pro">Days:</div>
      <div class="product-sale pro">UK</div>
      <div class="product-prize pro">7</div>
      <div class="button-buy pro">Buy now</div>
      <div class="add pro">Add</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav titlen pro">TESTING</div>
  <div class="nav pro boxp">
    <ul>
      <li class="active blc1"><span class="icon-tag f15"></span> '.$product["price"].'
        <br>
      </li>
      <li class="blc2"><span class="icon-time f15"></span> '.$product["stime"].'
        <br>
      </li>
      <li class="blc3"><span class="icon-plane f15"></span> '.$product["sto"].'
        <br>
      </li>
      <li><span class="icon-zoom-in f15"></span> '.$product["sto"].'
        <br>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product pro">
  <img class="product-img pro" src="'.$product[" imagesrc "].'"/>
  <div class="product-actions pro">
    <div class="info-block pro bl3" style="display:none;">
      <div class="product-title pro">Ships to:</div>
      <div class="product-description pro">Days:</div>
      <div class="product-sale pro">UK</div>
      <div class="product-prize pro">7</div>
      <div class="button-buy pro">Buy now</div>
      <div class="add pro">Add</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav titlen pro">TESTING</div>
  <div class="nav pro boxp">
    <ul>
      <li class="active blc1"><span class="icon-tag f15"></span> '.$product["price"].'
        <br>
      </li>
      <li class="blc2"><span class="icon-time f15"></span> '.$product["stime"].'
        <br>
      </li>
      <li class="blc3"><span class="icon-plane f15"></span> '.$product["sto"].'
        <br>
      </li>
      <li><span class="icon-zoom-in f15"></span> '.$product["sto"].'
        <br>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are my hero (today-) ! Many thanks.. One question which bugs still bugs me.. Why does my selector not works ?

Comment: Yours doesnt work because `parent().prev()` is null.  Parent is `ul`

Comment: Yes, like NorCalKnockOut said, [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selects only the immediate parent. Also, [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) selects only the immediately preceding element.

Comment: Is there anyway to see what value it is or to see what the selector contains ? I hope you understand my question. Like vardump($jqueryselector).

Comment: That would make it easier for me as a newbie to find the solution myself. Then I could have seen it did not contain class bl3.

Comment: You can check the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) of your selection. If it's zero, that element doesn't exist. `$(this).parent().prev('.bl3').length == 0`. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lue5s91w/).

Comment: Could I also done this by using CSS ? For example .blc3:hover > .bl3 { display:block;} ? Thank you.

Comment: Not unless you restructure your HTML. The traversal from `.blc3` to `.bl3` is currently too complex for CSS. Specifically, there is [not yet a "parent" selector in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).